# Alt key codes don't work on Ubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys, special-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using ALT + Keycode for accents?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32764/using-alt-keycode-for-accents)

When I press <kbd>alt</kbd> + number it doesn't print symbols as it does on Windows. For example, <kbd>alt</kbd> + 33 on Windows gives an exclamation mark (!) but it doesn't work on Ubuntu. Is it possible to enable it?

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/questions/32764/using-alt-keycode-for-accents. It answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press  combination and type:

```
gnome-keyboard-properties
```

Choose layout tab, and push the parameters button, in opened window, you will need to choose "Compose key position". For example - let's select Caps Lock. That's it. Try for press Caps Lock, then "o" then "c" keys on your keyboard - you should get this symbol - ©
Also, [link](http://www.schwarzvogel.de/compose.shtml)

Comment: your explanation is very vague.