# How do I insert special characters in Open Office?

Tags: openoffice.org

What is the shortcut to insert special characters in OpenOffice? In MS Word we type <kbd>Alt-0-1-8-8</kbd> to insert krutidev10. This shortcut is very important for us to be able to work quickly.

Comment: Does this work for you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-special-characters-like-e

Answer (score 2):

You can enter unicode codepoints by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-u</kbd> and then the codepoint you want to use. So if you type <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-u 0 1 8 8</kbd>, you will see an underlined `u0188` and then press <kbd>enter</kbd> and you will see `ƈ`.

Alternatively, you may want to check out the compose key, which will probably let you type faster. (System -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Layouts -> Options -> Compose Key, select a key to use, then press Close, and type in the test box to see how it works. E.g. <kbd>Compose ' c</kbd> will produce `ć`, same as above only with fewer keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer was posted in:

alt key codes on Ubuntu 10.04 doesn't work [closed]

The answer was:

See this [askubuntu.com/questions/32764/using-alt-keycode-for-accents](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32764/using-alt-keycode-for-accents). It answers your question. – Luke